# de Moivre’s martingale stopping time problem

Tags: probability, statistics, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $S_n$ be a random walk with $S_0 = 0$ and $0 < p < 0.5$. How to use de Moivre’s martingale $Y_n = (q/p)^{S_n}$ to show 
$E(\sup_{0\leq m\leq n}S_m)≤p/(1-2p)$?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the relation of $p$ and $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$? What do you mean by "random walk" (there are different definitions in the literature, so please state more precisely what you assume)

Comment: Well, I suppose that the book (or lecture) defines what "random walk" means before giving such an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive integers $w,n$, we have by [Doob's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob's_martingale_inequality)  that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0\leq m\leq n}S_m\geq w\right)=
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0\leq m\leq n}Y_m\geq (q/p)^w\right)\leq (q/p)^{-w}\,\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=(q/p)^{-w}.$$ 
Adding over $w$ gives 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{0\leq m\leq n}S_m\right)\leq \sum_{w=1}^\infty (q/p)^{-w}={p\over q-p}.$$